# Is $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ equivalent to the existence of the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Title pretty much says it all. I would think this should be true, but don't have much experience in this area of mathematics and don't know how to go about proving it.

Comment: What is your definition of $\Theta(g(n))$?

Comment: @abiessu Asymptotically bounded above and below by $g(n)$, or in both $O(g(n))$ and $\Omega(g(n))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $2 + \sin(n) = \Theta(1)$.

Comment: Although I believe it means both $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g (x)}$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g (x)}$ exist and is non-zero.

Comment: What if we add the condition that $f(n)$ is monotonic increasing?

Comment: @Laertes Then, the answer is yes. This is a consequence of the comment made by Arthur.